# Graphics.DrawString specify opacity of text

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing, opacity

Is it possible to specify the opacity of text written using the `Graphics.DrawString` method?

I'm doing something like this, but would like my text to be semi-transparent if it is possible.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);
graphics.DrawString("This is a watermark", 
    new Font("Arial", 40), 
    new SolidBrush(Color.Red), 
    0, 
    0);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try:

```
int opacity = 128; // 50% opaque (0 = invisible, 255 = fully opaque)
using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
using (var font = new Font("Arial", 40))
using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(opacity, Color.Red)))
    graphics.DrawString("This is a watermark", font, brush, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Note that `Graphics`, `Brush` and `Font` are IDisposable. You should always put them in `using` blocks.

Comment: Won't work very well if you end the `using` lines on semicolons though :p

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0x78FF0000))
```

Hope this helps